# Do I lose my BiA bonus if a crew member gets knocked out?

Tags: world-of-tanks

In WoT, the Brothers-In-Arms crew perk gives all crew members in your tank a 5% skill bonus, but only if it is trained to 100% on all of them.

If a crew member is knocked out in a battle and I don't use a first aid kit to revive them, does the rest of the crew lose that 5% bonus for the rest of the battle? 
 I know that when the Commander is knocked out, the rest of the crew loses their 10% Commander bonus, but does the same apply to the BiA perk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, Brother-In-Arms stays active, even when a crew member gets knocked out.

Source: [Wargaming wiki](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Crew)

Comment: Does it stay active if only one crew member is not KOed, though? I know that's an extreme case, but I'm curious.

Comment: Yes, it doesstay active